# Breaking while loop containing lists

Tags: r

I have a function that iterates polynomial expression on a predictor up until the linear model output shows that predictor without significance. This is all done in a `while(TRUE)` loop because I want to iterate all the degrees of a polynomial (unlikely I would actually need anything greater than 5), however I cannot get the loop to break properly. It should break when the length of the `lists` are 0 via `compact`.

For example:

```
regression_polynomial <- function(data, response_chosen, predictor_chosen){
  pmod <- c()
  pmod_I <- c() 
  i=0
  while(TRUE){
    i = i+1
    form <- reformulate(glue('poly({predictor_chosen},{i}, raw=TRUE)'), response=response_chosen)
     pmod[[i]] <- lm(form, data) %>% summary() %>%
      .$coefficients %>% data.frame(.) %>% rownames_to_column() %>% .[!(.$rowname) %in% "(Intercept)",] %>% 
     `colnames<-`(c('predictor', 'Estimate', 'Std.Error', 't-value', 'Pr(>|t|)')) %>% 
       remove_rownames() %>% split(., sort(as.numeric(rownames(.)))) %>% 
       lapply(., function(x){if(x$`Pr(>|t|)` < 0.05)x } ) %>% 
       compact() 
     length_pmod <- sapply(pmod, length)
     if(length(length_pmod) == 0){
       break
     }


  }
  return(pmod)
}
library(faraway)
regression_polynomial(savings, 'sr', 'pop15')
>Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `compact()` removes all elements, it will not return `NULL` but an empty object and that still ends up in `pmod`. Output vector length of `sapply(pmod, length)` is also the same as `pmod` length (i.e. never `0`) and thus `length(length_pmod) == 0` never evaluates to `TRUE`

Sample to illustrate:

```r
library(purrr)
pmod <- c()
str(pmod)
#>  NULL
pmod[[1]] <- list(a = NULL) %>% compact()
str(pmod)
#> List of 1
#>  $ : Named list()
length_pmod <- sapply(pmod, length)
str(length_pmod)
#>  int 0
# your break check condition if no results were returned on 1st cycle:
length(length_pmod)
#> [1] 1
```

But you could just drop the `length_pmod <- sapply(pmod, length)` and check the length of the last item in `pmod` vector for your break condition:

```r
ibrary(purrr)
library(dplyr)
pmod <- c()

pmod[[1]] <- list(a = NULL) %>% compact()
# compact() removed all items, time to break
length(last(pmod))
#> [1] 0

pmod[[1]] <- list(a = "not NULL") %>% compact()
# compact() kept something
length(last(pmod))
#> [1] 1
```